# Register a class with a manager, then call the sub classes overridden methods

Tags: c++, inheritance, game-engine, slice

OK so i have a few problems.
1. I need to be able to register the childclass when its created with game for broadcasting.
2. I need to be able to call the child class's method from an array of GameObject Pointers.
3. I need it to be the actual classes, not just copys of them.
In the file systemvars.h i have my global methods and some variables.

```
#pragma once
    //=================================
    // include guard
    #ifndef _SYSTEMVARS_H_
    #define _SYSTEMVARS_H_
//=================================
// forward declared dependencies
class Game;
//=================================
// included dependencies
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
//global enums
const enum CLASSTYPE{CLASSTYPE_NULL,CLASSTYPE_PLAYER,CLASSTYPE_DUNGION,CLASSTYPE_ENTITY,CLASSTYPE_MAP,CLASSTYPE_MENU};
//Global methods
void setGameRefrence(Game*);
Game* getGameRefrence();
```

systemvars.cpp: definitions

```
#include "SystemVars.h"
    static Game* curentgame;
    void setGameRefrence(Game* mygame)
    {
        curentgame = mygame;
    }
Game* getGameRefrence()
{
    return curentgame;
}
```

In my Game.h: a holder for gameobjects

```
#pragma once
    //=================================
    // include guard
    #ifndef _GAME_H_
    #define _GAME_H_

//=================================
// forward declared dependencies
class GameObject;
//class Player;
//=================================
// included dependencies
#include "SystemVars.h"
#include "GameObject.h"
//#include "Player.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
//=================================
// the actual class
class Game
{
public:
    Game(void);
    void registerGameObject(GameObject*);
    void unregisterGameObject(GameObject*);
    void sendMessageToAllObjects(string message,CLASSTYPE recipeint);
    ~Game(void);
private:
    GameObject *gameobjects2[1000];
    int numberofobject;
};
#endif
```

the game.cpp gameclass definition

```
#include "Game.h"
    //#include "Player.h"

Game::Game(void)
{
    setGameRefrence(this);
    //logHelperMessage(INFO,1,"Registerd game");
    numberofobject = 0;
}

void Game::registerGameObject(GameObject* newobj)
{
    //logHelperMessage(INFO,1,"Registerd");
    newobj->setId(numberofobject);
    gameobjects2[numberofobject] = newobj;
    numberofobject++;
    //gameobjects.push_back(newobj);
}
void Game::unregisterGameObject(GameObject* objtodie)
{
    //logHelperMessage(INFO,1,"Unregister");

    for(int i = objtodie->getId();i < numberofobject - 1;i++)
    {
        gameobjects2[i] = gameobjects2[i+1];
        gameobjects2[i]->setId(i);
    }
    gameobjects2[numberofobject-1] = nullptr;
    numberofobject--;
}
void Game::sendMessageToAllObjects(string message,CLASSTYPE recipeint)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < numberofobject;i++)
    {
        cout << "Sent the message from game");
        //((Player *)gameobjects2[i])->sendMessage(message);
        //static_cast<Player*>(gameobjects2[i])->sendMessage(message);
    }
} 
Game::~Game(void)
{
}
```

Gameobject.h: the parent of my inner game classes.

```
#pragma once
    //=================================
    // include guard
    #ifndef _GAMEOBJECT_H_
    #define _GAMEOBJECT_H_

//=================================
// forward declared dependencies
enum CLASSTYPE;
//=================================
// included dependencies
#include <iostream>
#include "SystemVars.h"
using namespace std;

//=================================
// the actual class

class GameObject
{
public:
    GameObject();
    GameObject(CLASSTYPE mytype);
    ~GameObject(void);
    virtual void sendMessage(string data);
    virtual CLASSTYPE getMyClassType();
    virtual void setMyClassType(CLASSTYPE newrecip);
    void setId(int val);
    int getId();
protected:
    CLASSTYPE _MYCURRENTCLASSTYPE;
    int myid;
};
#endif
```

Gameobject.cpp

```
#include "GameObject.h"

GameObject::GameObject() : _MYCURRENTCLASSTYPE(CLASSTYPE_NULL)
{
    //do not register
}

GameObject::GameObject(CLASSTYPE mytype): _MYCURRENTCLASSTYPE(mytype)
{
    //register this object into the gameobject list.
    getGameRefrence()->registerGameObject(this);
}


GameObject::~GameObject(void)
{
    getGameRefrence()->unregisterGameObject(this);
}

void GameObject::sendMessage(string data)
{
    //logHelperMessage(INFO,1,"Recived te message in GameObject");
    cout << "Recived te message in GameObject";
}

CLASSTYPE GameObject::getMyClassType()
{
    return _MYCURRENTCLASSTYPE;
}

void GameObject::setMyClassType(CLASSTYPE newrecip)
{

}
void GameObject::setId(int val)
{
    myid = val;
}
int GameObject::getId()
{
    return myid;
}
```

Player.h:

```
pragma once
    //=================================
    // include guard
    #ifndef _PLAYER_H_
    #define _PLAYER_H_
//=================================
// forward declared dependencies
//=================================
// included dependencies

#include "SystemVars.h"
#include "GameObject.h"
//=================================
// the actual class
class Player : public GameObject
{
public:
    Player();
    void sendMessage(string data) override;
    void test();
}
```

Player.cpp:

```
Player::Player() : GameObject(CLASSTYPE_PLAYER)
    {

    }
void Player::sendMessage(string data)
{
    //logHelperMessage(INFO,1,"Recived the message in Player");
    cout << "Recived the message in Player";
    //logHelperMessage(INFO,1,data.c_str());
    cout << data;
}
void Player::test()
{
cout << "Sent message";
    getGameRefrence()->sendMessageToAllObjects("Test",CLASSTYPE_PLAYER);
}
```

main.cpp

```
#pragma once
#include "SystemVars.cpp"
#include "Player.h"
#include "Game.h"
Game mygame;
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    setGameRefrence(&mygame);
    Player newplayer = Player();
    newplayer.test();
}
```

Now that that is all out of the way.
The expected output is:

```
Sent message
    Sent message from game
    Recived message in Player
```

but insted i get:

```
Sent message
    Sent message from game
    Recived message in Gameobject
```

Im pretty sure i have a sliceing problem, but im not sure what to do about it, or where it is.
So, any ideas gents?

ALso, i tried to cut back the classes a bit so im not posting 2000~ lines of code. So if anyhting missing let me know.
About a dozen classes inherit from gameobject. and i need them all to talk to eachother in one way or another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just by having CLASSTYPE_PLAYER, etc. makes me concerned that you're trying to subvert/reinvent C++ OOP. You already have the concept of 'class' in the language, why re-invent it? Forgive me if I'm wrong. Aside from this, I suggest you look up publisher-subscriber frameworks to do the kind of thing you're after, or implement your own. I'm sure somebody will answer your C++ issue more directly.

Edit: tone of first comment.

Comment: I'm just trying to set up a broadcast. Basically anywhere in the program i want a way to send a message. Such as sendmesage("+5gold1",CLASSTYPE_Player); So every single player that's registered in the game gets the message. and then let them decide whether or not they want to do anything about it.

Comment: Sounds like pub-sub to me.. I used it in a Java project couple of years ago but have not in C++, try look it up and good luck.

Comment: seems similar but i have no clue how to apply this =/

Comment: Ok I got your code to build and run, and it seems to work fine. 
I got the following output: **Sent message/Sent the message from game/Recived the message in PlayerTest** In Game::sendMessageToAllObjects() I used the code
'gameobjects2[i]->sendMessage(message);' I still wouldn't use this technique however.

Comment: See this for inspiration, although I can't vouch for the implementation. [link](http://www.cs.sjsu.edu/~pearce/modules/patterns/events/pubsubimp.htm) Your Game class would be the publisher and Player, etc. would be subscribers.

Comment: Youre code as posted didn't build. I had to add the odd #Include or #endif, but one line in particular is not valid, '#include "SystemVars.cpp"' in main.cpp. Of course I had to remove that or I got 'multiply defined' link errors. Apart from that, just the line I mentioned above. It's fairly simple code, you have an array of objects you call a method on to send a message.